# Simple SQL Query Help Required

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table

```
uid  |  rid
-----------
1    |    4
1    |   13
2    |    4
3    |   13
```

I want my query to return the uid where it has rid = 13 AND does not have rid = 4 so the result would be 3

So far I have

```
SELECT distinct uid
FROM test
WHERE 
ur.rid <> 4 
AND ur.rid = 13
```

but of course this is returning 1 and 3

What am I missing from my query to get only 3?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT uid
FROM test t1
WHERE t1.rid = 13
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM test t2
                  WHERE t2.uid = t1.uid
                    AND t2.rid = 4);
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/392409)**</kbd>

or using aggregation:

```
SELECT uid
FROM test
GROUP BY uid
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN rid = 13 THEN 1 END) > 0
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN rid = 4 THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/392412)**</kbd>

EDIT (by gordon):

The above answer is fine.  I'm just adding this as a simplification to the second query (it didn't seem appropriate to put in a separate answer and it is too long for a comment):

```
SELECT uid
FROM test
GROUP BY uid
HAVING SUM(rid = 13) > 0 AND
       SUM(rid = 4) = 0;
```

It takes advantage of a nice feature of MySQL.

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15334e/1/0)**</kbd>

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks I didin't know MySQL supports that. Great usage of boolean condition. Added it to my toolbelt :)